# Simple Dom Parser get span values in Table

Tags: php, simpledom

I am using [Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and I am trying to get some info from a dynamic table that will look like this:

```
<table />
<tr>
   <td class="histogram-msg top-row">5 star</td>
   <td class="top-row bar-cell"><span class="bar bar5" style="width:150px">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span>55</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="middle-row histogram-msg">4 star</td>
   <td class="middle-row bar-cell"><span class="bar bar4" style="width:65px">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span>24</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="middle-row histogram-msg">3 star</td>
   <td class="middle-row bar-cell"><span class="bar bar3" style="width:38px">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span>14</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="middle-row histogram-msg">2 star</td>
   <td class="middle-row bar-cell"><span class="bar bar2" style="width:19px">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span>7</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="bottom-row histogram-msg">1 star</td>
   <td class="bottom-row bar-cell"><span class="bar bar1" style="width:35px">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span>13</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying grab the values in the table i.e. : 5 star | 55, 4 star | 24, etc.

I get this info by `$ret = $html->find('.user-ratings');` and when I try to print the span tags it just give me a bunch of white space.

How can I grab the rating type and value from the table above?

Comment: If the values are being loaded with JavaScript, you won't be able to use a DOM parser to get that information.

Comment: When I get the html contents from the table div I can see all the values so I don't think they are JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you're trying to do:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$f = file_get_html('s.html');

foreach($f->find('td[class=histogram-msg]') as $n) {

foreach($n->parent()->find('td[class=bar-cell]') as $p) {
    $ratings[] = array('stars' => $n->innertext, 
   'rating' => strip_tags(str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $p)));
    }
}

print_r($ratings);

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [stars] => 5 star
        [rating] => 55
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [stars] => 4 star
        [rating] => 24
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [stars] => 3 star
        [rating] => 14
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [stars] => 2 star
        [rating] => 7
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [stars] => 1 star
        [rating] => 13
    )

)
```